# Adding features to ESB cluster

Tags: wso2

You've a cluster of WSO2 ESB. You only access to the management console in the manager instance of the cluster, and the workers get the configuration and registry through G-Reg, while local artefacts are shared through SVN.

Then you add a new feature (let say you add DSS to ESB) from a p2-repo, then restart the server and the management server has the new feature added.

what's the way to propagate this new feature across the cluster??

Comment: Hey @GustavoH, this is awesome! but I really need to know how you did that I totally need it!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'll again answer my own question, just in case somebody else find it useful.

There is no way to share features within a cluster. You'll have to either connect to the worker nodes through the master console or arise the console in the workers, and manually add the features.

I've tried to use the master to create an image to clone to the workers, but I had troubles with the SVN of the cluster, so it was unsuccessful.

If you're working in a cloud environment, don't forget to change the worker image your workers are cloned from.

Be aware that if you add Roles to the master node, those Roles **are** being propagated to the workers (even though the features don't).